# change datatype of key of a map inside complex structure in spark (scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Consider a spark dataframe with the schema below

```
 |-- cart: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- cart_items: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- activities: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- original_price: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- amount: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- currency: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- price: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- amount: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- currency: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- participant_count: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- key: integer
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = true)
```

My goal is to change the type of the **key** element inside the map *participant_count* from integer to string, so the final schema would be

```
 |-- cart: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- cart_items: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- activities: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- original_price: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- amount: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- currency: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- price: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- amount: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- currency: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- participant_count: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = true)
```

I tried the following

1. Create a custom UDF that changes the datatype of the key inside a map

```
    val convertKeysToString_only_maps = udf((column_with_map: Map[Any, Int]) => {
      if (column_with_map != null) {
        column_with_map.map { case (key, value) => (key.toString, value) }
      } else {
        null
      }
    })
```

2. use the **.withField** property to change the structure of the dataframe & apply the udf in the right part

```
var df_converted: DataFrame = df
   .withColumn(
     "cart",
     $"cart".withField(
       "cart_items",
       $"cart.cart_items".withField(
         "activities",
         $"cart.cart_items.activities".withField(
            "participant_count",convertKeysToString_only_maps($"cart.cart_items.activities.participant_count"))
       )
     )
   )
```

However I obtain the following error

========================================================================================
[DATATYPE_MISMATCH.UNEXPECTED_INPUT_TYPE] Cannot resolve "update_fields(cart.cart_items.activities, WithField(UDF(cart.cart_items.activities.participant_count)))" due to data type mismatch: Parameter 1 requires the "STRUCT" type, however "cart.cart_items.activities" has the type "ARRAY<STRUCT<....

========================================================================================

I believe the issue is because the field **activities** is an array of structs instead of a struct itself, which would make, I believe, **.withField** method fail. However, how can I interact with such a complex structure? I have tried changing the UDF many times without success